# unable to access the public_html folder using ftp client

Tags: ftp, web-hosting, ftp-client, filezilla, winscp

I'm confused why I can't access the public_html folder on my server using Filezilla or WinSCP. The result is either Access denied (WinSCP) or Critical Error, Could not connect to server (FZ). I created my own ftp account, I can access the Cpanel using the hosting, i create mysql acct as well..

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you created the ftp user with a private home directory . You should create it and make sure that the website home directory is its home diertory too which is public_html

Answer (score 0):

While creating the ftp account please, set the Directory path name to public_html to see the project files.